# Изменение Where по условию

Tags: oracle, plsql

В функции курсор собирается селектом вида:

WITH A AS 
(select)
B AS (select from A)
SELECT * FROM B

Мне необходимо, чтобы в зависимости от поступившего в функцию параметра, в этом селекте выполнялось where по одному из полей таблицы:
т.е. поступило 1, значит where pole1 = 1
поступило 2, значит pole2 = 1 и т.д.

Можно ли реализовать такое, потому что писать несколько одинаковых селектов нет желания, т.к большие объемом?

Comment: `where (:X=1 and pole1=1) OR (:X=2 and pole2=1)` или даже `where decode(:X,1,pole1,2,pole2)=1`. где `:X` пришедшее число. правда совершенно не ясно, какое отношение к вопросу имеет наличие в запросе WITH

Comment: Включил, чтобы поподробнее описать вопрос. Спасибо, decode работает

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать CASE in WHERE

```
function SOME(.., v_flag ..)
....
begin
  ..
  WITH A
    AS (select)
     , B
    AS (select from A)
  SELECT * FROM B
  where case v_flag
          when 1
          then pole1
          when 2
          then pole2
          else something_else
        end = 1
  ..
```

Comment: Спасибо, хороший вариант.